# Cannot retrieve values from LEFT JOIN (2 tables)

Tags: mysql

Here it is my query:

```
$query_products = "
SELECT 
    p.Id
    , p.product_sku
    , p.product_name
    , p.hide_product
    , p.new_style_image
    , p.ext
    , p.product_thumb_image
    , p.product_full_image
    , SUM(s.stoc_final)
    , s.active 
FROM 
    produse p 
    LEFT JOIN stoc_intern s ON p.product_sku=s.cod_website 
WHERE 
    (
        (" . $product_sku_search . ") 
        OR (" . $product_name_search . ") 
        OR ("  .$product_culoare_search . ")
    ) 
    AND p.hide_product != 'd' 
GROUP by p.product_sku 
ORDER BY SUM(s.stoc_final) DESC 
LIMIT " . $items_per_page . " 
OFFSET " . $_offset . "";
```

My problem is: the last field I'm selecting, the s.active one, has in the table the value of "n" but when I display it, it shows empty (`echo $s_active`);
If I change the field `s.active` with say other field `s.description`, it will work.

Also, in the table "`stoc_intern`" some fields that I select do display well, some do not display a thing (even if table data contains info).

Why is that?

Comment: I bet it's because of the non-standard usage GROUP BY. When you omit non-aggregate columns in the GROUP BY clause (which is not allowed in other DBMS) MySQL more or less chooses a random row.

Comment: what should I do ? do you have a reccomendation ? should i GROUP BY p.product_sku, s.active ?

Comment: now it's working. I took your comment's advice and fiddled a bit with the code...so instead of GROUP BY p.product_sku I wrote GROUP BY s.active, p.product_sku. And now it displays as before with the ability of getting the s.active field in the row data. Thanks !!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That causes so many issues. I still don't know why they allow it by default. You can shut it off with the [`only_full_group_by`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) sqlmode option

Comment: @DTest: I agree. It's another one of those stupid MySQL "features" that no one can really understand.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you should put this is in as the answer and get credit for it

Comment: Are you sure that the limit value and the offset values are valid (assuming you really have matching data)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a_horse_with_no_name already provided with the answer.

But to disable this *"one of those stupid MySQL "features" that no one can really understand"*, you can set `sql_mode` to be more strict about it. Consider the following setup in your `my.cnf` config file:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
```

See [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by). This will not allow you to reference non-grouped columns unless with an aggregation function.